# TypeError: L2.__call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype' Keras

Tags: keras, typeerror, dtype

I got this error
TypeError: L2.**call**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

when i created layer

next_layer= Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=regularizers.l2(0.01))(next_layer)

using google colab

any help ?
thanks inadvance

```
next_layer=GlobalAveragePooling2D()(output)
next_layer=Dense(1024, activation='relu')(next_layer)
next_layer=Dense(512, activation='relu')(next_layer)
next_layer = Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=regularizers.l2(0.01))(next_layer)
next_layer=Dense(2048, activation='relu')(next_layer)
```